# Unable to resume actvity in facebook implementation

Tags: android

i tried to implement facebook login in to my application... when i am trying to run the application first time, it shows error message like unable to resume activity.. `java.lang.nullPointerException..`

```
   Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookLogin.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat error. AFAIK you might have not declared the facebook login activity in your manifest file. `<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />`

Comment: Post logcat here...needed it

Comment: 09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.javaE/AndroidRuntime(20433)android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2486)
E/AndroidRuntime(20433):android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600

Comment: 09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(AuthorizationClient.java:136)
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(LoginActivity.java:117)
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1158)
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4544)

Comment: 09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1158)
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4544)
09-23 16:19:06.942: E/AndroidRuntime(20433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)

Comment: 09-23 16:19:22.102: E/AndroidRuntime(20933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 16:19:22.102: E/AndroidRuntime(20933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException